# Button not showing up in P-table

Tags: angular, typescript

I am running into an issue where a button is not showing up while I have it in my p-table. It shows up (But doesn't download the csv) outside of the table (I want it outside but I am unsure if it will work without being inside of the table). Here is the code for the p-table

```
   <p-table #DropOff [value]="userData" [(selection)]="selectedUser" selectionMode="multiple" [rowHover]="true" [columns]="cols" [paginator]="true" [rows]="25" [rowsPerPageOptions]="[25,75,200]">

    <button type="button" pButton icon="fa fa-file" iconPos="left" label="Selection Only" (click)="DropOff.exportCSV({selectionOnly:true})" style="float:right"></button>
```

I left out the entries below but the table is filled out. I have tried everything I can think of but for someone reason if it is outside of the table (where I want) it does not download the csv but if it is inside the table, it will not even show the bottom to attempt to download it.

Answer (score 0):

Forgot to add the caption ng template and it resolved my issue.